# UIWebView : do not use internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I save a webpage into a NSData object which is stored in an document.
Then I want to load it back into an UIWebView.

So I transform the document into an NSString

```
let myHTMLString = NSString(contentsOfFile: readPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
```

And I load it into my UIWebView doing

```
webView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
```

Which actually works.

The aim is to save a website, and display it afterwards, in an offline mode.
If the phone is in airplane mode, the UIWebView fails to download css, images and displays the static page (which is what I want)

But if the phone is connected to Internet, the UIWebView will use the network to load those dynamic contents (css, images ...)

Is there a way to prevent the UIWebView to use the network so that it will act as the phone would be in airplane/offline mode ?

(I could parse the html and remove some tags, but it would not be that easy)

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965180/how-to-download-a-web-page-with-its-inner-resoures-like-images-css-in-ios

Comment: I've been wrestling with something similar, and I have a word of warning: only use this with *very* simple pages.  If the pages have JavaScript or JQuery, etc, the WebView won't be able to handle them properly.  I ended up having to set up a virtual server within my own app to make those pages work.